# How do I select variables in map and mutate?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, purrr

It seems like I need a refresher on how to select using different tidyverse. Why do the map/mutate selections behave differently than the dplyr select?

Question 1: How are we supposed to map/mutate every column except one (named). Why does '-"ID"' not work like in select? It is completely counterintuitive to me.

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(ID = 1:10, 
                 a = 1:10,
                 b = 1:10,
                 d = 1:10,
                 e = 1:10)

df %>% map_at(-(1:3), as.character) # this works
df %>% select(-"b") # this works
df %>% map_at(-"b", as.character) # Why does this not work?
df %>% map_if(colnames(.)!="b", as.character) # there has to be a better way

df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(Sum = sum(-ID)) # I get why this does not work, but how do I do this?
df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(Sum = sum(select(., -ID))) # This way I loose the rowwise operator
df %>% mutate(Sum = apply(df %>% select(-ID), 1, sum)) # there has to be a better way
```

How about mapping everywhere except the last column?

```
df %>% map_at(-ncol(.), as.character) # is there a better way?
```

Question 2: How do I select columns (by name) with the ':' operator?

```
df %>% select(a:e)
df %>% map_at(a:e, as.character) # doesn`t work. How do I do this?
df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(Sum = sum(a:e)) # misleading - Does it just use a? Why no error?
df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(Sum = sum(a,b,d,e)) # this wont work with hundrets of variables
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the docs (`?map_at`) the `.at` argument takes

> A character vector of names, positive numeric vector of positions to include, or a negative numeric vector of positions to exlude.

Hence `-c(1:3)` works as it is a negative numeric vector of positions to exclude. But you can't do `-"b"`. For this case you have to use `vars()` from `tidyselect`.

Using `vars()` you could fix the two non-working example of your first question and the first of your second question:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% map_at(vars(-b), as.character)
#> $ID
#>  [1] "1"  "2"  "3"  "4"  "5"  "6"  "7"  "8"  "9"  "10"
#> 
#> $a
#>  [1] "1"  "2"  "3"  "4"  "5"  "6"  "7"  "8"  "9"  "10"
#> 
#> $b
#>  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
#> 
#> $d
#>  [1] "1"  "2"  "3"  "4"  "5"  "6"  "7"  "8"  "9"  "10"
#> 
#> $e
#>  [1] "1"  "2"  "3"  "4"  "5"  "6"  "7"  "8"  "9"  "10"

df %>% map_at(vars(-ncol(.)), as.character)
#> $ID
#>  [1] "1"  "2"  "3"  "4"  "5"  "6"  "7"  "8"  "9"  "10"
#> 
#> $a
#>  [1] "1"  "2"  "3"  "4"  "5"  "6"  "7"  "8"  "9"  "10"
#> 
#> $b
#>  [1] "1"  "2"  "3"  "4"  "5"  "6"  "7"  "8"  "9"  "10"
#> 
#> $d
#>  [1] "1"  "2"  "3"  "4"  "5"  "6"  "7"  "8"  "9"  "10"
#> 
#> $e
#>  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

df %>% map_at(vars(a:e), as.character)
#> $ID
#>  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
#> 
#> $a
#>  [1] "1"  "2"  "3"  "4"  "5"  "6"  "7"  "8"  "9"  "10"
#> 
#> $b
#>  [1] "1"  "2"  "3"  "4"  "5"  "6"  "7"  "8"  "9"  "10"
#> 
#> $d
#>  [1] "1"  "2"  "3"  "4"  "5"  "6"  "7"  "8"  "9"  "10"
#> 
#> $e
#>  [1] "1"  "2"  "3"  "4"  "5"  "6"  "7"  "8"  "9"  "10"
```

Similarly for your question using `rowwise`. You can't pass several columns to `sum` using e.g. `a:e`. Instead you have to wrap inside `c_across`:

```
df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(Sum = sum(c_across(a:e)))
#> # A tibble: 10 × 6
#> # Rowwise: 
#>       ID     a     b     d     e   Sum
#>    <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#>  1     1     1     1     1     1     4
#>  2     2     2     2     2     2     8
#>  3     3     3     3     3     3    12
#>  4     4     4     4     4     4    16
#>  5     5     5     5     5     5    20
#>  6     6     6     6     6     6    24
#>  7     7     7     7     7     7    28
#>  8     8     8     8     8     8    32
#>  9     9     9     9     9     9    36
#> 10    10    10    10    10    10    40
```

And a second option for the last operation would be to use `rowSums` with `across`:

```
df %>% mutate(Sum = rowSums(across(a:e)))
#>    ID  a  b  d  e Sum
#> 1   1  1  1  1  1   4
#> 2   2  2  2  2  2   8
#> 3   3  3  3  3  3  12
#> 4   4  4  4  4  4  16
#> 5   5  5  5  5  5  20
#> 6   6  6  6  6  6  24
#> 7   7  7  7  7  7  28
#> 8   8  8  8  8  8  32
#> 9   9  9  9  9  9  36
#> 10 10 10 10 10 10  40
```